# Notify user when there is a very slow internet (2G) connection - iOS

Tags: ios, notifications, xcode7, reachability, network-connection

I am using Reachability library in my project which allows me to check whether there is any connectivity but what I am trying to do now is to notify the user if the connection is 2G or very slow. This is causing an issue when user is on a GSM call and tries to interact with the app while the internet is set to 2G. I would like to notify them and perhaps say that they should change their mobile data settings or connect to Wifi. I have been trying to use CTTelephonyNetworkInfo code inside the connectivity check block but it does not notify the app when internet is low and sometimes I can duplicate messages from this call. Any ideas?

```
switch (_tcpipReachability.currentReachabilityStatus) {
    case ReachableViaWiFi:
        self.networkAccessible = (self.wifiReachability.currentReachabilityStatus != NotReachable);
        break;
    case ReachableViaWWAN:
        self.networkAccessible = self.useOperatorBearer;
        break;

    case NotReachable:
    default:
        self.networkAccessible = NO;
        break;
}

//connection type
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *netinfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];

if ([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyGPRS]) {
    NSLog(@"2G");
} else if ([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyEdge]) {
    NSLog(@"2G");
} else if ([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyWCDMA]) {
    NSLog(@"3G");
} else if ([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyHSDPA]) {
    NSLog(@"3G");
} else if ([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyHSUPA]) {
    NSLog(@"3G");
} else if ([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMA1x]) {
    NSLog(@"2G");
} else if ([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORev0]) {
    NSLog(@"3G");
} else if ([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORevA]) {
    NSLog(@"3G");
} else if ([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORevB]) {
    NSLog(@"3G");
} else if ([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyeHRPD]) {
    NSLog(@"3G");
} else if ([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyLTE]) {
    NSLog(@"4G");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why bother with all that complexity?  Network issues happen outside of 2G, so why pick on this one network?

Simply find a way of measuring the network performance you are getting in your app (which is number of bytes received in a one-second interval) and then simply alert them to slow performance, which might impact on their experience with your app.

Or simply ignore the whole thing altogether and let them figure it out themselves.

Comment: You are right, but we have noticed most of the issues with 2G on while on a GSM call. Most users would eventually check their connection if they see nothing is happening in the app but we want to make sure they know its not us and its their connection. I guess I could give the network performance a try or just pop up a message on timeout.